# Como retornar el valor de una variable desde una funcion

Tags: funciones, powershell

Necesito retornar el valor de las variables desde una función. Esta es la función, pero las variables me las devuelve vacías.

```html
function listcert
{
    Get-ChildItem "P:\" -name
    Write-Host ""
    [string] $path = Read-Host -Prompt "Specify the path or the certificate "

    if ((Get-Item "P:\$path") -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo])
    {
        Get-ChildItem "P:\$path" -name
        Write-Host ""
        [string] $certificate = Read-Host -Prompt "Specify the certificate "
        $pass = Read-Host -Prompt "Set the password for the certificate: "
        [Security.SecureString] $mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass -Force –AsPlainText
    }

    else
    {
        $pass = Read-Host -Prompt "Set the password for the certificate: "
        [Security.SecureString] $mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass -Force –AsPlainText
    }

    Remove-PSDrive P
    return ,$path
    return ,$certificate
    return ,$mypwd
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al realizar el return devuelve inmediatamente el valor de la variable que asociaste, te aconsejo que construyas un array con las variable $path, $certificate, $mypwd y hagas el return del array

```
$arreglo['path']=$path
$arreglo['certificate']=$certificate
$arreglo['mypwd ']=$mypwd 

return $arreglo;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Leonardo y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. aquí puedes aprender de las [funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utiliza la instrucción `return`, el valor se devuelve inmediatamente y la ejecución vuelve a la persona que llama.

En *PowerShell*, todos los valores enviados al `pipleine` (flujo de salida) son el valor de retorno, por lo que sólo necesita la instrucción `return` si desea detener la función de inmediato.

Tampoco necesita usar la coma `unary` para crear una matriz. Usted ya está retornando 3 variables para que sea una matriz, por lo que sólo puede separar todos los valores con comas:

```
return $path,$certificate,$mypwd
```

... y puesto que los devuelve al final de la función, tampoco necesita la declaración `return`:

```
$path,$certificate,$mypwd
```

### Información adicional

Debe cambiar los parámetros de su función `take` en lugar de usar `Read-Host` para leerlos en tiempo de ejecución. Esto ofrece más flexibilidad al llamar a la función, y si establece los parámetros `_mandatory` (obligatorio), *PowerShell* solicitará al usuario si no se proporciona el valor.

Considere el uso de un objeto `[PSCredential]` en lugar de `[SecureString]`. Es más fácil de usar y la propiedad `.password` de la credencial ya es una cadena segura.

Ejemplo:

```
function listcert
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $Path ,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $Certificate ,

        [Parameter()] # No es obligatorio para que podamos personalizar
        [PSCredential]
        $Credential = (Get-Credential -UserName Ignorado -Message 'Set the password for the certificate')
    )
    Get-ChildItem "P:\" -name

    if ((Get-Item "P:\$path") -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo])
    {
        Get-ChildItem "P:\$path" -name
    }
    Remove-PSDrive P

    $path,$certificate,$mypwd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías devolver las variables como un PSObject:

```
return New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   Path = $path
   Certificate = $certificate
   Password = $mypwd
}
```